# installing torch 1.0.1.post2 in windows system

Tags: pytorch

Not Able to install latest version of Torch (pip install torch==1.0.1.post2)

```bash
pip install torch==1.0.1.post2
```

Trying to do in Python Version 3.7 and windows 10

```bash
C:\Users\Admin>pip install torch==1.0.1.post2
Collecting torch==1.0.1.post2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.0.1.post2 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1)
No matching distribution found for torch==1.0.1.post2
```

Answer (score 0):

torch 1.0.1.post2 is not available on Windows. You can get a list of all available torch pypi packages from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/stable